# How to integrate outlook calendar API into React JS application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Actually when I log in to the Microsoft online login with this API [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tanent_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btanent_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) and use the token response into this API headers https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events to add an event into the outlook calendar then I found this kind of error.

[image]

Is this a token error? Or How to solve it? I am working on a React JS app to integrate outlook calendar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you license the user for Exchange Online/provision a mailbox? This endpoint corresponds to calendar events, and in order to fetch those you need to have a mailbox.