# How to integrate outlook event calendar & teams API into the React JS & React Native Applications?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Actually when I login into the Microsoft online login with this API.

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{taentId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtaentId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) API to get access token and I got the response of token but when I try to use that token into this API to create the event *https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events*. I got this error **Resource could not be discovered.
**

Also Sharing a response of the login api

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "email openid profile Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared Calendars.ReadBasic Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared User.Read User.Read.All",
    "expires_in": 5***,
    "ext_expires_in": 5***,
    "access_token": "eyJ0*************",
    "id_token": "eyJ0********"
}
```

[image]

*How Can I Solve This Error ?*

Comment: Check similar questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74810594/how-to-integrate-outlook-calendar-api-into-react-js-application